# How to route VPN connection?

Tags: vpn, routing, ubuntu-12.04, ethernet, ubuntu-server

I want to connect to a VPN server - running Ubuntu Server 12.04 - using `eth0` and route its output to `eth1` so I can connect my home PC to `eth1`. How can I achive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume your server has a single Linux based firewall and the following two Ethernet cards:

eth1 (public IP) ============== {INTERNET}
eth0 (internal network /192.168.0.0/24) ==============  192.168.0.1

*tun0 is configured as 10.8.0.1 as a VPN, with the whole VPN network configured as 10.8.0.0/24.*

In such case, iptables rules required for this to work, looks like this:

```
 # Allow traffic initiated from VPN to access LAN
    iptables -I FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 \
         -s 10.8.0.0/24 -d 192.168.0.0/24 \
         -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

    # Allow traffic initiated from VPN to access "the world"
    iptables -I FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth1 \
         -s 10.8.0.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

    # Allow traffic initiated from LAN to access "the world"
    iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 \
         -s 192.168.0.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT

    # Allow established traffic to pass back and forth
    iptables -I FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED \
         -j ACCEPT

    # Notice that -I is used, so when listing it (iptables -vxnL) it
    # will be reversed.  This is intentional in this demonstration.

    # Masquerade traffic from VPN to "the world" -- done in the nat table
    iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth1 \
          -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE

    # Masquerade traffic from LAN to "the world"
    iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth1 \
          -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

Hope it could help.